# Questions about recalling US Senators / Representatives

Tags: discussion

We currently have three questions addressing recalls of US Senators or Representatives:

- [Colorado](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/is-there-a-procedure-to-recall-us-senators)
- [Texas](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/can-i-recall-my-us-senator-or-representatives-in-congress)
- [Utah](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/can-i-recall-my-us-senator-or-representatives-in-congress-in-the-state-of-utah)

Since they're all about different states, they're not technically duplicates, but since they all have the same answer ("You can't"), I feel like they should be.

Does it make sense to ask the general question "How can I recall...", answer it with as authoritative answer as possible, then close the others (and any future ones) as duplicates pointing to the generic one?  Should we leave them as-is and just accept one per state?  Is it too soon to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a federal-level issue, these really *are* functionally all duplicates (i.e. *"How to recall a Senator in <state> where 'state' is largely irrelevant?"*).

So, sure, the best way to handle this situation is to write a really killer, authoritative answer to this question and redirect any question asking for this information to that one awesome resource. **We call this a "canonical answer"** and it's a great way to answer an often-asked question once and for all, while redirecting anyone who might be looking for this information to a helpful resource created by this site.

Comment: Cool.  Now someone just needs to write it.  I might tackle it at some point, if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @Bobson, feel free to I will remove mine if your answer addresses the following. The common misconception that those 18 states that allow recalls are only for state and local officials (perhaps links to each states constitutions, Secretary of State FAQ, or similar). A link/quote from the Congressional Research Service, or other primary source that explains why the tenth amendment doesn't apply, and perhaps links to advocacy groups (motherjones, carp, etc.) common arguments and why they are wrong.